# How observableArray works with options binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Just started learning Knockoutjs from official site , I am pasting the code from step 3 of [this](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) excercise.

**View**

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>

 <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
   <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
        <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
```

**View Model**

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);

      // Operations
    self.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

I would like to know how `ko.observableArray` works with `options` binding, how the price row gets updated when dropdown value changes ?

Is it because seats array is  `observableArray` so the price property remain sync in the `UI` ?

I even tried debugging in chrome, but  when dropdown value changes no function get's hit.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the price gets updated because of the `SeatReservation.meal` observable since it is bound to `value` in your html template.

So when you used `meal().price`,  you are accessing the object inside the meal observable, and accessing the price property.

Its the same as writing:

```
<td data-bind="text:price"></td>

function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal){
this.price = ko.pureComputed(function(){
   return this.meal().price;
});
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the select tag attribute `value: meal` ?

Comment: Ok, but observables should be declared as `meal()` right ? then why `value: meal` is used ?

Comment: You only use `meal()`, when you want to access the object inside the observable, it's like a `get` function. `value:meal` is used because you are passing the `observable` itself and not the object inside it.

So the `options` binding  changes the value of the `meal` observable when the user selects other options.

Comment: +1 , Ok  like `Jquery`, In `Knockout` why I am not able debug and see which function gets hit when drop down changes ?

Comment: Since the `options` binding automatically changes the `meal` observable, you can debug it by subscribing to the `this.meal`. 

`this.meal.subscribe(function(meal){  console.log(meal.price);})`

Comment: Ok it seems we can't check by adding break point in chrome , so whenever user changes option , `SeatReservation` constructor is called internally and in UI  price values is updated right ?

Comment: One last doubt when meal is observable then the property like mealName, price also become observable and thus any change in the property updates the UI right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172715/discussion-between-jmarioste-and-stom).